# How do I call Combox.Text from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

In form 1 I have placed Comboxbox component and I have done this...

```
string value = cBAdmin.Text;
```

I want to leave that Comboxbox in form 1 but I want call that Comboxbox from another class and do rest of the coding. How do I do this? Thanks in advance if anyone can help me here.

Comment: Well it depends. Why do you want to do this ? It could help us tell you how **or** help us explain why you should change your design

Comment: in anyway i feel what you want to do.. google how to create user control and use wpf

Comment: you want to call `ComboBox` or its property?

Comment: Why don't you just pass the string variable into your method that assemblies SQL queries? You just need to rewrite your SQL method to accept another string....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very bad idea, but you can expose it a a public textbox, or you can expose the value through a get property, something like

```
public string TextBoxValue { get { return cBAdmin.Text; } }
```

Comment: thanks and I will take your and eveyone's advise that it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are **not** going to call the Combobox properties **from a different thread**, you can do something like this. I am not sure if this is what you are looking for??

```
Foo c = new Foo( cBAdmin );
c.DoSomethingWithComboBox();

public class Foo
    {
        private ComboBox m_cb;
        public Foo(ComboBox cb)
        {
            m_cb = cb;
        }
        public void DoSomethingWithComboBox()
        {
            //Do something with m_cb
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @svcrcoder - thanks and I will take your and eveyone's advise that it is a bad idea.